# Get File ID from Google Drive with PHP

Tags: preg-match, extract

I have been looking for a way to extract the ID of a file in Google Drive, and well both looking for information and some similar functions, I have managed to find this, it works for me, but I hope they can polish it a little more.

```
    <?php
function get_drive_id_from_url($url)  {
    preg_match('/\/d\/(.+)\//', $url, $result);
    return $result[1];
}

echo get_drive_id_from_url('https://drive.google.com/file/d/FILE_ID/view?usp=sharing');
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use another delimiter than `/` you don't have to escape the forward slash. You can make use of `\K` to forget what is matched so far, followed by matching any character except `/`

Then assert a `/` directly to the right using a positive lookahead.

As this does not use a capture group, the result is in `$result[0]`.

```
/d/\K[^/]+(?=/)
```

The pattern matches:

- `/d/` Match literally
- `\K` Clear the match buffer
- `[^/]+` Match 1+ times any char except `/` (or `[^/\s]+` to also not match a whitespace char)
- `(?=/)` Positive lookahead, assert `/` directly to the right

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/HI1Vmf/1) and a [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/nTJ9i).

Example code

```
function get_drive_id_from_url($url)
{
    preg_match('~/d/\K[^/]+(?=/)~', $url, $result);
    return $result[0];
}

echo get_drive_id_from_url('https://drive.google.com/file/d/FILE_ID/view?usp=sharing');
```

Output

```
FILE_ID
```

The capture group variant of the updated pattern is:

```
/d/([^/]+)/
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/up5w3d/1)